# Casting videos from Android without Internet WiFi connection

Tags: android, casting

Given that I have a video file on my Android device, is it possible to cast to a TV without Internet WiFi availability?

The answer is simple if you are at home, and have your own Internet WiFi available: just use Chromecast. But Chromecast requires a connection.

I imagine this is a problem for anyone that's in a location with electricity, but no Internet connection, so there must be a way.

Comment: Copy the video into a USB stick and play it on your TV. Why do you want to cast?

Comment: @SamuelRobert you make a good point.  Either way, you're going to have to plug something into a random "hotel" TV (either a USB stick or HDMI based dongle).  In my case, I've got stuff I want to watch already on my phone, and watch on the plane, but I could copy to a USB stick using an 'on the go' connector.